# Strange CSS effect in Bootstrap. Unintentional indent when showing numerous content divs inside container div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, indentation

I'm using Bootstrap as CSS framework for a project me and my friend is working on (hence the D&D theme). I have a page where we're displaying a specific users D&D characters. When displaying these characters on the page there is supposed to be four on each row (span4's in a row-fluid). The problem is that there is a strange indentation starting on the second row (see attatched fiddle).

I've been using "Inspect component" in Chrome but I can't seem to get what makes this happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/sE5en/4/

Hope I explained the problem somewhat :)

The main "container" (essentially the ) is pasted below:

```
  <div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <h3 class="mycharacters">My characters</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-small pull-right">
            <i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add character
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="span12" id="actor_result"><div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4 well well-small"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle actor" src="http://placehold.it/64x64"></a><div class="overflow-media-body media-body"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="actor_edit_owner?id=1"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
                                    </a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-picture"></i> Change avatar</a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul></div><h4 class="media-heading">Davius</h4><div><i class="icon-heart"></i><strong> Health: </strong>17/20hp</div><br><br></div><div><i class="icon-fire"></i><strong> Effects: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">Mumblecore bushwick sed, nulla id street art dolore delectus wolf american apparel artisan sriracha.
Laboris seitan hoodie, freegan brooklyn letterpress adipisicing chambray mixtape id tofu organic butcher small batch. Art party carles readymade messenger bag williamsburg. Irony placeat sustainable, high life cillum yr sed vinyl pork belly messenger bag williamsburg VHS. Occaecat lo-fi readymade gluten-free 3 wolf moon. Ad tofu twee, blog nulla mumblecore gentrify brooklyn odio cliche selvage put a bird on it pork belly chillwave deserunt. Ea assumenda chillwave, keytar velit tumblr pour-over enim VHS mcsweeney's blog.</div><div><i class="icon-edit"></i><strong> Notes: </strong></div><div class="actor-text"></div></div></div>
<div class="span4 well well-small"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle actor" src="images/avatar/actor/leonidas.png"></a><div class="overflow-media-body media-body"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="actor_edit_owner?id=3"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
                                    </a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-picture"></i> Change avatar</a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul></div><h4 class="media-heading">Awesome Maximus</h4><div><i class="icon-heart"></i><strong> Health: </strong>1/30hp</div><br><br></div><div><i class="icon-fire"></i><strong> Effects: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">DYYYING! öööääöååå</div><div><i class="icon-edit"></i><strong> Notes: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">lol</div></div></div>
<div class="span4 well well-small"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle actor" src="http://placehold.it/64x64"></a><div class="overflow-media-body media-body"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="actor_edit_owner?id=4"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
                                    </a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-picture"></i> Change avatar</a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul></div><h4 class="media-heading">Master Thief Sven</h4><div><i class="icon-heart"></i><strong> Health: </strong>10/13hp</div><br><br></div><div><i class="icon-fire"></i><strong> Effects: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">Lurking</div><div><i class="icon-edit"></i><strong> Notes: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">He's a backstabber</div></div></div>
<div class="span4 well well-small"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle actor" src="http://placehold.it/64x64"></a><div class="overflow-media-body media-body"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="actor_edit_owner?id=5"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
                                    </a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-picture"></i> Change avatar</a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul></div><h4 class="media-heading">Giant Frederic</h4><div><i class="icon-heart"></i><strong> Health: </strong>25/27hp</div><br><br></div><div><i class="icon-fire"></i><strong> Effects: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">Farting</div><div><i class="icon-edit"></i><strong> Notes: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">I will cruuuush you!</div></div></div>
<div class="span4 well well-small"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle actor" src="http://placehold.it/64x64"></a><div class="overflow-media-body media-body"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="actor_edit_owner?id=6"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
                                    </a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-picture"></i> Change avatar</a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul></div><h4 class="media-heading">One eyed idiot</h4><div><i class="icon-heart"></i><strong> Health: </strong>35/35hp</div><br><br></div><div><i class="icon-fire"></i><strong> Effects: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">Rested</div><div><i class="icon-edit"></i><strong> Notes: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">Can't see straight</div></div></div>
<div class="span4 well well-small"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle actor" src="http://placehold.it/64x64"></a><div class="overflow-media-body media-body"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="actor_edit_owner?id=7"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
                                    </a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-picture"></i> Change avatar</a></li><li><a href=""><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li></ul></div><h4 class="media-heading">Pantless bum</h4><div><i class="icon-heart"></i><strong> Health:   </strong>5/7hp</div><br><br></div><div><i class="icon-fire"></i><strong> Effects: </strong>  </div><div class="actor-text">Stinks like you wouldn't believe</div><div><i class="icon-edit">    </i><strong> Notes: </strong></div><div class="actor-text">Needs help...</div></div></div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indentation comes from the fact that you're lining up a stack of divs that exceeds the grid limitation of 12 columns per line, so the grid elements past the 12 column mark are indented per design. You can evade this by lining up just 3 `.span4` divs per `.row-fluid` (4x3=12) or targeting that fourth grid element with some css magic and removing the margin, like so:

**CSS**

```
.row-fluid > .span4:nth-child(4) {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Of course, the `nth-child` selector is not supported in older browsers (such as IE7-8) but you can replace the CSS with some jQuery if you want to expand support.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sE5en/5/show/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, both of you! I went with Andres answer and it really worked like magic on page =)

Comment: @user1392042 I'm glad it worked!, quick tip, if you want to have more elements in your page fit nicely within your container simply replace `.span4:nth-child(4)` with `.span4:nth-child(3n+1)`. This selector will target every fourth grid element in your container and remove the margin-left nicely.

Comment: Wow, thanks again, the number of characters on the page could be any number so this helped a lot. Just didn't realise that the fix was generic for all number of characters :)

Comment: @user1392042 yeah i figured, here is a demo with multiple rows of grid elements with the fix in place: http://jsfiddle.net/sE5en/7/show/

Comment: I came across a problem with this implementation...Every time when I use the span4 class it gets pushed all the way to the left. This is not a wanted effects when I'm combining this with the "offset" class in Bootstrap. I can have a div like this <div class="span4 offset 3"></div> which push a span4 div 3 steps to the right. But the CSS fix posted earlier overrides this class. =/

Comment: @user1392042 is that div you want to offset part of your `#actor_result` container? If not, you can easily fix that by only targeting that container which you wish to have the fourth element properly indented like so: `#actor_result .row-fluid > .span4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left:0;
}`.. This is the way it should be, since the fix i posted above will target all `.row-fluid` elements in your doc.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is not strange, but expected. It is defined in bootstrap.css on line 343:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    ...
    margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
    *margin-left: 2.074468085106383%;
    ...
}
```

and on line 218

```
[class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

First div in a row has overridden margin on line 355:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I don't think you can override margin setting when row contents spans through multiple rows in a cross-browser compatible way, so you should put every 3 character divs in a separate row.
I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sE5en/6/) so you can see the difference.